# Unable to access the Windows drive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, mount

I am trying to open the E(called New Volume) drive of windows in Ubuntu 14.04 and it gives me this error message

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/nisarg/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/nisarg/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

It used to be perfectly accessible only now its not.What's wrong? I logged into windows and did a shutdown as well but the same message crops up.
Help .

Comment: @NoTime But [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) is the original question for all who faces this type of error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that does seem better (as it is community one), maybe the one I directed should be sent there as well. I am sorry I do not wish this to be a conversation.. not sure how to send PM or open chat normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Windows 8 then fast-startup (aka fast-boot, and quick-boot) must be turned off. When you click "Shutdown" or "Restart" with fast-startup enabled the computer doesn't actually shutdown it just goes into a minimal deep hibernation state to make it look like Windows boots quickly. This means the Windows kernel is still partially in control of hardware even after you boot into another operating system. Under some circumstances this then causes problems such as mounting issues.

## Steps:

1. In Windows 8 go to the Start Screen. [You can do this by clicking the bottom left corner of your screen.]
2. Right click on some empty space, and click "All Apps".
3. Click on "Control Panel". [You may need to search around for it.]
4. In the control panel choose "System And Security".
5. Click on "Change what the power buttons do". [It's a submenu.]
6. Uncheck the checkbox for "fast-startup", and click "save changes".
7. Shutdown the computer. [Use "Shutdown" not "Restart" just this once.]

## Notes:

- Obviously disabling fast-startup means Windows 8 will now **appear** to boot up a bit slower.

Comment: thanks a lot! but one thing is still not clear. The fast boot was enabled since a long time and i could mount the drive perfectly fine up until yesterday.. so any other possibility?

Comment: the problem is indeed solved now

Answer (score 2):

While in Windows:

Open Command prompt which you find in All Programs > Accessories (right click and left click run as admin) and type : powercfg -h off

Restart into Ubuntu and you should be good to go.  You will lose the hibernate ability but now can access the disk and read and write to it.

hope that helps...

If not, use "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2 or 3 or 5" according to the error specified