# unable to mount New Volume from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, windows-8, hibernate

This question has been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464630/unable-to-access-the-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04).

I have a dual boot system with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 but I am not able to open New Volume from Ubuntu. It gives the following error:

[image: error]

I disabled the hibernate option using

```
powercfg /h off
```

but it did not work although it was able to disable the `hibernate` and `fast boot` option.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: see [ignis's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/499541/283843) there ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be some problem in your ntfs partition.

You can fix it using `ntfsfix`

Open terminal and type

```
  sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
```

After successful completion of command try to remount the portition.