# how to recover files from hard disk, missing partition and hard disk check (horror movie described by an informatic incompetent)

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, data-recovery, live-cd

i have a really big problem with a pc (xp) of a friend whose hard drive is detected both by bios and setup, but when going on lubuntu with a live cd it doesn't show off neither any partition from the sata disk, just ram stuff.

I'm pretty sure there was as i could access the files before, but when i turned the pc off and on again it kind of started deleting the system files of windows xp trying to correct the errors and now ubuntu does not even find the partition neither the disk.

I'd like to know what happened and how to recover important data from the drive

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLQIM.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeN1y.jpg

as you can see here without the live the pc won't do anything usefull, the stats tell that there is Sata2, the Disks and gParted and df cannot find the partition

To explain myself better, in fig 1 you can see SATA2 IDE hard disk that is a 500 Gb hard disk.

In fig 2 you can see that this disk can't be seen with the commands or programms i know that should make you see it.

I may be ignorant in the subject so forgive me in case of confusion or such

EDIT: i've opened the pc, cleaned all and checked the connections, now the folder of the 500 GB is back (don't know if it's correlated because even before i could access) but as folders of user it tells me it is a corrupted file. What the hell is going on? Help me understand that machine please

EDIT2: disappeared again, so i'm sure the thing is going, the Disk option told me its status and that was at 40°C, could not open it, neither it let me use gParted, i'm a lot more confused now, please someone may tell me what is going on?

Comment: not the same since i cannot find the partition, that link is about mounting when you know which partition is NTFS

Comment: The link mentioned before deals exactly with broken or missing partition table, PBR and parts of the MFT.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271

Comment: yep missing partition but at least it detects the hdd with the fdisk -l command. There it seems that for ubuntu the driver is not even plugged and even if the motherboard detects it (fig 2 and 1)

Comment: Maybe i should re-edit fig 2, in the top left there is the fdisk output and the df.
In the bottom left the Gparted with only the partition of the cd from which i'm doing the live.
In Disks on the right just the ram and the disks. No sd no hdd detected as it is not even plugged, for this i think it's different from the case you keep referring, am i wrong? in that case i'm sorry to keep complaining

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: @Marco, OK I see what you mean now. But if there is hardware failure we can't really help much.

Comment: I could read it fine with the live CD, then i resetted the machine just to check, the auto-correction of system error of xp ran and it deleted something like system files, now it seems to me that i cannot even detect it with ubuntu(fig2), yet the motherboard(fig1) tells that the SATA2 is linked and it's fine, i could feel the hdd running when i opened to check for death, and, as i said in the edits, i could detect it once ater randomly turning the pc on and off following the oldest informatic rule.
I hoped you could tell me what it is going on as anyone of you has more experience than me.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto  i mean... how could it be an hardware problem if the motherboard tells me it's fine and if i was able to read it before and to detect it once randomly?

Comment: The fact that a drive is detected by the motherboard doesn't mean the SATA cable is not damaged, or that the disk controller is working fine or that there isn't any other damage present there.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment. Maybe this can help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/464630/unable-to-access-the-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04