# No internet in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I am able to access internet (wired and WiFi) on my laptop when I use Windows 10 but not with Ubuntu 14.04. The modem is working perfectly fine, there is no problem with modem, however when I open Firefox in Ubuntu I get an error "server not found". I am not able to use internet through wired or WiFi connection in Ubuntu.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Coropration Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
[8086:008b] (rev34)
            Subsystem: Intel Coropration Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5315]
            Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card
Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
--
10:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083]
(rev c0)
           Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1651]
           Kernel driver in use: atlid

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep iwl`:

[image]

Comment: which wifi card do you have?

Comment: @ravery : I have edited my question and added a picture, kindly check that. 
I do not know what a wifi card is but what ever I have understood I have taken a screen shot and shared it.
If you need more info please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Intel Centrino 1030 -- is the wireless card. be sure you have universe and multiverse/restricted repositories enabled. then browse firmware packages to see if one addresses your card drivers

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'Eth|Net'` terminal command. Please post is as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: ok , i will @Pilot6

but there is a new problem now, I am unable to access hard disk from ubuntu.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/464630/unable-to-access-the-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04

i have tried this but still no help.

Comment: mangesh@mangesh-HP-pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no

- @Pilot6

Comment: Please add information TO YOUR QUESTION for both commands.

Comment: When i add the terminal output in the question, it is comming in continuous set of words, how come you are able to format it properly and present it as the output obtained in terminal? strange 
@Pilot6

Comment: Select the text and pres the `{}` button.

Comment: Kindly check the update 3, I am sorry, i tried copying the code but I am unable to access hard disk from ubuntu so i don't know how to save the copied data. Please check the link in "edit 3"

Comment: All looks OK. Try my solution.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying @DavidFoerster but i am facing another problem as well, I am unable to access hard disk from ubuntu, so i am unable to save program output.

Comment: @KabirSharma: You don't need storage access to save program output. On a live system you can still save files to the home directory or `/tmp` to open in a text editor or upload it to a pastie service. They will vanish after shutdown/reboot though. If you want to "extract" the file to use it on a different system and don't have network access you need some external storage medium, e. g. a USB drive or a memory card. The USB drive used to boot the live system will work for this usually.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the command

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot will fix the wireless problem.