# can I format c drive while ubuntu installed in other drive

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dual-boot, windows

I have dual boot my computer on a single HDD having windows in C drive and ubuntu installed in other drive.
Can I format C drive and reinstall windows in C drive without affecting Ubuntu which is already installed ?
Do I need to follow any specific path to do so or I should proceed with normal procedure.

I am facing one more problem that, Previously I was not able to access windows drive from ubuntu So I tried solution given on [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464630/unable-to-access-the-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04) . After that I was able to access but now again I am unable to access the drives. Please help me with the best solution for the above two mentioned problems

Comment: Reinstalling Windows, unless you are an expert, is *likely* to destroy your Ubuntu install and lose all your data. Windows assumes that it's the only OS on the machine (it usually is). The second question has been answered many, many times - use the 'Search' box.

Comment: See also: [Ubuntu Documentation: RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 0):

yes. but there are tons of caveats and ways to break things.

First: backup data you care about! regardless of reinstalling windows

Your problem doesnt require windows reinstall. just boot the install cd, and try to "fix boot". it will surely remove linux boot, which you will have to fix later on.

before anything (after the backup :) if your bios has any efi option, disable it. if it has safeboot, disable it. if it show anything like "legacy boot" enable that one.

lastly, stop saying drive. you mean partitions. read more on partitioning, because not understanding it is a sure way to lose your linux if you install windows.